# Calling a @classmethod in a child class give a 'TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type'

Tags: python, class, dictionary, inheritance, typeerror

I'm making a custom dict, a simple translation database. This class has a class method to read and mount the object from a file. I sum some concepts of initialize my super class with child class to be ready to use, empty, and then fill it out with kwargs using my methods, a custom class method constructor to provide this kwargs from a file.

```
class TransDatabase(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()    # init the dict parent
        """do args"""

    @classmethod
    def fromfile(cls, file):
        kwargs = cls.__load_file(file)
        return cls.__init__(kwargs)    # return the custom class constructor
```

so that's strikes:
`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: `return cls.__init__(kwargs) ` is just wrong, `cls.__init__` always returns `None` anyway. `__init__` is technically an "initializer" not a constructor. To call the constructor, use `cls(**kwargs)`

Comment: What @juanpa.arrivillaga said. Plus, I think you are using Python 2 and not Python 3. In Python 2, `super` had to be provided with the current class and the superclass, while in Python 3 this is done automatically.

Comment: @1313e Python 3 gives the same error as well.   `__init__` was just called with a class not an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` is an instance method.  In the class method, create an instance of the class by calling it:

```
return cls(**kwargs)
```

Example:

```py
class TransDatabase(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)    # init the dict parent

    @classmethod
    def fromfile(cls, file):
        kwargs = {'a':3,'b':4}  # no __load_file defined, so fake it
        return cls(**kwargs)    # return the custom class constructor

t = TransDatabase(a=1,b=2)
print(t)
t = TransDatabase.fromfile('dummy')
print(t)
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: For sure, I'll keep that in mind, thanks.